# remove alphanumeric with 2 alphabets followed by 2 digits

Tags: r, regex, gsub, alphanumeric

```
a <- c("it is ZZ10ASDJN123 and ZZ100DD22")
```

How can i remove the words starting with first 2 alphabets followed by starting 2 digit numbers
and not remove any alphanumeric more than follows 2 + digit numbers.

Expected output:

```
"it is and ZZ100DD22"
```

This code removes the numbers alone. Please help in geting me the expected output.

```
gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("\\s*\\b[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}(?!\\d)\\w*\\b", "", a, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SvraIX/1). An alternative:

```
gsub("\\s*\\b[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}[A-Za-z_]\\w*\\b", "", a)
```

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` - two ASCII letters (use `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letters)
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?!\d)` - there can be no digit immediately to the right
- `\w*` - 0 or more letters, digits or underscores
- `\b` - word boundary.

Add `(*UCP)` at the start of the regex to make it fully Uniocde-aware.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/Q2vXCm):

```
a <- c("it is ZZ10ASDJN123 and ZZ100DD22")
gsub("\\s*\\b[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}(?!\\d)\\w*", "", a, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "it is and ZZ100DD22"
```